# How to Capture Num Keypad Keys using cvWaitKey openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

Is there any way to capture which numeric key was pressed from the Keypad using `cvWaitKey` in openCV. I tried using the codes from this [list](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html) from adobe but they don't work.

When I try to print out the value of the key pressed, I get no value for the numpad keys.

Can anyone help on this?

If not how to do this in C++?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is a standard for keyvalues, anyhow if you are using Gtk as a gui, it will use the keyvalue-attribute of a GdkEvent structure: here you can find the keycodes for these: http://www.koders.com/c/fidD9E5E78FD91FE6ABDD6D3F78DA5E4A0FADE79933.aspx

If you are using Qt it will *probably* use QKeyEvent::key(), but I could not verify this, see: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QKeyEvent.html

For win32 it uses these:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx

For carbon, I am not sure, I would guess something like this: http://snipplr.com/view/42797/

You could decide to define your own keycode-mapping based on these (for the keys you need), since as far as I know none exists.

Good luck!